# Is there any Bitcoin Exchange that doesn't have fees for euro SEPA deposits/withdrawals?

Tags: exchanges, marketplace, exchange-fees

Since Tradehill disappeared, which was really sad, I cannot find any Bitcoin exchange that let's me deposit and withdraw euros without fees, while they do for US dollars.
Both Mt.Gox and Intersango have a 10-20 PLN fee that their bank charge. While Bitstamp has a 0.90 EUR fee + a EUR-USD conversion rate.
Note that I'm looking for a real exchange, not for a person-to-person service like Bitmarket.eu or Bitcoin.de.

Comment: Probably not, for now.

- http://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Selling_bitcoins

Comment: @stevenroose: the Intersango SEPA fee is not 10-20 PLN, it is exactly 5 PLN, which is about 1.23 EUR. Both in and out. That is not that much. Well, and if its such a problem, just open yourself and account in Bank Zachodni WBK in Poland - they your transfers between you account and Intersango will be free - both in and out. Just one trip to Poland with your passport and perhaps some paper with your address - can be foreign. The EUR account is free of monthly charges, you can also deposit and withdraw EUR from it in cash for free in branches (in Poland).

Comment: They could simply open a bank account in a full EU country where bank transfers are free...
EU law states that SEPA fees cannot be higher than national fees. Most EU countries have a law that says that national transfers have to be totally free, so SEPA has to as well. But seemingly the Polish law still allows fees for national transfers as well

Comment: by the way about bitecoin.de you have to pay some fees per transaction plus for disbursement (to transfer your BC in your personal wallet, out of their site)

Answer (score 1):

Would a non-bank transfer work?  How about getting a realoadable prepaid debit card and using that for spending / ATM use?

Comment: A reloadable debit card? A debit card for spending / ATM use can't perform it's own internet payments as far as I know. They are linked to your bank account so in se, it's just the same as doing a bank transfer.
I could try some payment site and use a credit card, but credit cards always involve fees, which are avoidable with regular bank transfers.

Answer (score 1):

[Bitcoin Central](https://bitcoin-central.net/) from France which just got a [payment services processor license](https://bitcoin-central.net/s/aqoba-partnership?locale=en) and as you mentioned: Bitstamp from Slovenia? I would go with the regulated French exchanger.

Comment: Does it have no SEPA fee?

Comment: I checked, it has no fee for deposits, 0.99 EUR for withdrawals. Reasonable :)

Comment: Bitstamp has free Euro deposits and a 0.90€ fee for Euro withdrawals.
Also, according to [https://www.bitstamp.net/about_us/](Bitstamps about page) the company is located in UK.